# How to write a regular expression for the given language?

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

This question wants me to write a regular expression over the following language:
*L = {w  | w has exactly two a's and at least three b's}*
(and the alphabet is {a,b})

I have dealt with this by drawing it's NDA at first and then writing a regular expression for my NDA. But it's way harder than I thought and probably not working for this question.
My NDA (which I think is incorrect):

[image]
So far the regular expression I came up with seems way too long (to answer the need for exactly two a's and at least three b's. I considered every possible premutation for minimum requirements)

Am I doing it in a correct way? Or, Is there any way to answer this question without drawing NDA?

Comment: Will you please upvote my answer?

Comment: Yes. Done :))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact trivially possible to make a *DFA* for the language with $13$ states, $12$ corresponding to "seen $i$ a's and $j$ b's" where $0\le i\le2$ and $0\le j\le 3$ and one reject state. Making a regular expression, though, does require casework on the possible permutations of b's among the (considered fixed) a's; there are $10$ ways to distribute three b's in the three spaces (left, middle and right), and they force $10$ different subexpressions without union:
$$\mathtt{b+ab+ab+|b++ab+a|b+ab++a|b++aab+|b+aab++|ab++ab+|ab+ab++|b+++aa|ab+++a|aab+++}$$
where $\mathtt{b+}^n$ is shorthand for $\mathtt b^n\mathtt{b*}$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your answer. You mean the final expression will be: (bb∗abb∗abb∗ | bbb∗abb∗a | bb∗abbb∗a | bbb∗aabb∗ | bb∗aabbb∗ | abbb∗abb∗ | abb∗abbb∗ | bbbb∗aa | abbbb∗a | aabbbb∗) ?

Comment: @FarbodMirkazemi yes, yes...

Comment: Thank you very much.